# Ruby windows installer

Tags: ruby, css, sass, rubygems

I seek recommendation of which version of Ruby to install as I'm trying to install Ruby to get SASS -or as of css3 I should say SCSS- (as a gem). I know nothing about Ruby and I do not want to get into problems by installing the improper version of Ruby, I just want the SASS. I run Win 10 64-bit, I head to the download site [Ruby installer for windows](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)

I read the "WHICH VERSION TO DOWNLOAD?", but can't seem to decide which version to pick depending on my machine.

Comment: I am not a Windows User, but I recommend to go with Ruby 2.2.5
An advice to you install Ubuntu its pretty easy on it.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://rubygems.org/gems/sass/versions/3.4.22, which is the page for that gem, anything greater than or equal to 1.8.7.

I would go ahead and install the latest version 2.3.1x64

Answer (score 0):

I recommend installing the latest **stable** version (unless you are exploring the latest features in the newest version, which you are not). The notes on the side will tell you which one is **stable** by saying the version they **recommend**:

> If you don’t know what version to install and you’re getting started with Ruby, we recommend you use Ruby

Also, on Windows, you will most likely need to install **DevKit** if you are installing any gems that contain native `c` code.